# bundle install error, unexpected ':'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know there are bunch of question or similar on the web, but it doesn't fit my case.
I'm installing redmine, and when I call `bundle install`, I get this error :

```
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: compile error - syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin, :jruby]
                            ^. Bundler cannot continue.
```

The error is on this line (the one prefixed by `->`):

```
   source 'https://rubygems.org'

   if Gem::Version.new(Bundler::VERSION) < Gem::Version.new('1.5.0')
     abort "Redmine requires Bundler 1.5.0 or higher (you're using #{Bundler::VERSION}).\nPlease update with 'gem update bundler'."
   end

   gem "rails", "4.2.3"
   gem "jquery-rails", "~> 3.1.3"
   gem "coderay", "~> 1.1.0"
   gem "builder", ">= 3.0.4"
   gem "request_store", "1.0.5"
   gem "mime-types"
   gem "protected_attributes"
   gem "actionpack-action_caching"
   gem "actionpack-xml_parser"
   gem "loofah", "~> 2.0"

   # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
-> gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :x64_mingw, :mswin, :jruby]
   gem "rbpdf", "~> 1.18.6"

   # Optional gem for LDAP authentication
   group :ldap do
     gem "net-ldap", "~> 0.3.1"
   end
```

like it's said in so many other threads, a cause could be that this code use the "new" ruby 1.9 hash syntax. However, looking at the versions:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
$ gem -v
2.2.2
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.10.6
$ bundle exec ruby -v
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
$ which bundler
/usr/local/bin/bundler
```

**EDIT: as suggested by Arsen, this command shows where is the problem, I'll read some documentations about ruby and virtual environments to get it work the right way :**

```
$ bundle env
Environment

    Bundler   1.10.6
    Rubygems  1.8.24
    Ruby      1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux]
    Git       2.5.1

Bundler settings

    without
      Set for your local app (/home/leo/http/redmine.leo-flaventin.com/redmine/.bundle/config): "development:test"

Gemfile
   [...] #The redmine Gemfile
```

Then, I think gem is using ruby 2.2 (but I'm not sure) so I think there shouldn't be any problem, but since I don't really know the ruby universe and there is actually an error, I'm certainly wrong. That's why I request the help of the community...

So any ideas of what is going on ?

(I could correct the file using the old hash syntax, but since I would like to use the latest versions, I think that would only move the problem)

Comment: Note : I posted this here since I don't think it's a redmine-related problem, but a ruby version one

Comment: Do you use RVM? And what does `bundle exec ruby -v` give you?

Comment: `$ bundle exec ruby -v` outputs : `ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux-gnu]` (same as `ruby -v`) I added it to the post since it could be relevant, ty :)

Comment: `bundle` is a small script which calls `bundler` from the rvm. If you run `which bundler`, what is the output?

Comment: `$ which bundler` outputs `/usr/local/bin/bundler`

Comment: Now show us `bundle env`

Comment: It is difficult to handle dependencies if you are not using RVM for your rails installations. I'd strongly suggest to leave aside system installations and create your own virtual environment, where you will have full control of your gems and dependencies.

Comment: (Unfortunately, i have a bad memory, but) if i remember right, i had a similar issue on a debian server, i downgraded bundler from 1.10.x to 1.7.x and it worked.

Comment: Arsen got the point^^ `$bundle env` outputs `Ruby      1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux]`

Comment: @Ruby Racer : I start to understand that I won't be able to use redmine out of box without learning the basics of managing ruby... I guess it's like python venv, I should use a virtual env for each project

Comment: I am also facing the exact issue only while I am trying to start the redmine through /etc/rc.local , otherwise if I am starting the redmine after login, there is no issue.      command "                                                            cd /var/www/html/redmine;bundle exec rails server webrick -e production -b 172.16.3.12 -p 80 -d "

Comment: If you 're facing the same issue, try to use rvm or similar as mentioned in the comments. That's how I've made it work

Answer (score 1):

This is a old question but since it is unsolved and I ran into the same problem I'll share my solution.

I installed ruby via apt-get on my debian 7 server. When trying to run bundle install I got the same error message as above:

[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: compile error - syntax
error, unexpected ':', expecting $end

My soultion was to install ruby via ruby version manager.

1. Remove ruby `sudo apt-get remove ruby && sudo apt-get autoremove`
2. Install ruby via ruby version manager (rvm) `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable --rails`
3. If 2. fails, add signature (as prompted) `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | sudo bash -s stable --rails`
4. Add user to group `sudo usermod -aG rvm USERNAME && sudo usermod -aG rvm www-data`
5. Logout & login
6. Re-run your `bundle install` command
7. If you still have problems they should be application relevant. For me I additionally had to install `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev`.

I've seen this solution while following a tutorial on this [blog](https://nidomiro.de/2015/03/installing-redmine-3-0-on-clean-ubuntu-14-04/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `ruby "2.1.5"` to Gemfile

Or just use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)

Comment: just adding `ruby "2.1.5"` to the Gemfile didn't work, but now that I know that bundle really uses `1.8` I will document myself to use virtual env :)

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me when I got the same error installing a new app with rails 5:

```
gem install rails --version=5.0.0.1

bundle install
```

I do not know why it worked.